# Unable to set short name on document clause so that it can be added to word template

Tags: template, omnistudio, contracts, vlocity

I am using the CLM feature of Salesforce and want to generate a contract document using document templates. I have a Word document with the text and some of the text there, is clauses that may be used across different templates.

So I decided to create the clauses in Salesforce. And according to the documentation I created the Document Clause Set and then later added the clauses under that set. Now in the documentation, it is mentioned that I need to define a short name on the clause so that it can be used in the Word document. But I don't see any such field on the document clause object.
[image: Document Clause Creation Screen]

Are there any additional permissions required or is there any setting that I have missed to configure? Can somebody please help me out?